# running a django webapp in python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, virtualenv, pip

I am using python 3.3 in a virtualenv in a macosx machine, when I installed django 1.5 alpha release after untarring django 1.5 and running following command

```
pip install -e Django-1.5a1
```

it looks like django is installed, when I run 
    pip freeze

following is the output

```
Django==1.5a1 
Pygments==1.5
South==0.7.6
bpython==0.11
distribute==0.6.28
django-debug-toolbar==0.9.4
django-extensions==1.0.0
ipython==0.13.1
logilab-astng==0.24.1
logilab-common==0.58.1
pylint==0.26.0
```

clearly django is installed however import django doesn't seem to be working when I run the following

```
import django
```

in python shell inside virtualenv, the output is

```
No module named import django
```

what can be the problem with this setup

Comment: Uhm, it works for me. Are you sure you activated your environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like pip does not work for installing this version, I used setup.py and everything seems to be working now.